# how to replace an array with an associative array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of old strings and I want to replace it with an array from mysql. instead the strings are replaced with the word "Array"

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'select replacement from myTable');
$svgstr = file_get_contents ($file.svg);
$pattern = array ("str1" => '/oldstr/', "str2" => '/oldstr/');
$replacement = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $newstr[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $svgstr);
```

I expect the elements of the pattern to be replaced with the mysql table but instead I get ........ Array .......... Array.
thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newstr[$i] = $row['replacement'];
```

You have to use the column name you are requesting the data to access the value of `$row` array.